# Spivak's Calculus 5.9: Prove that $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} f(a+h)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Please critique or vote on the proof I supply as a response. Thanks!

Definition of a Limit: The function $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$ means that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta >0$ such that for all $0< |x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x) - l| <\epsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any function $f$ such that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = l$ for some some $l \in \mathbb{R}$. We must show that $\lim_{h \to 0}f(a+h) = l$. First consider any $\epsilon >0$. By our definition of limits, we know that there's some $\delta >0$ such that, for all x, where we have $0< |x-a|<\delta$, we also have $|f(x)-l| <\epsilon$. Consider the case where $x=a+h$ where $h \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $|f(x)-l| <\epsilon$ where $0< |x-a|< \delta $ for which we replace $x$ with $a+h$, i.e. we have the following $0< |x-a| = |a+h-a|=|h-0|<\delta$.

In other words, when $0<|h-0|<\delta$, we know that $|f(a+h)-l| <\epsilon$ which is what we needed to show.

Comment: I'm not sure why you wrote $h-0$ instead of $h$

Comment: In the definition above, the way the delta is defined is that $0<|x-a|<\delta$. So for me to show that $f(a+h)$ approaches $l$ when $h$ tends to $0$, I wrote $|h-0|$ to be a bit pedantic in showing that $h$ tends to 0.